# Statistics on Facebook shares

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, share-button

I want to add a share button inside an iOS app and wonder if it is possible to get any statistics of how many people have used the shared button inside my app? When people use the share function they will share an image from their phone and not any URL. I wonder if facebook already have any built in function for this or if I need to track the clicks programmatically.

Thanks in advance! 
Vatan

Answer (score 1):

Google will allow you to do tracked links for Android, so there must be an equivalent for IOS. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-url-builder

There is a way to add trackable links and analytics using SWIFT, according to Google. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

Answer (score 0):

Look into App Events. You can define your own events for actions users take in your app, and then you can evaluate them in Facebook Analytics for Apps.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I must add tracking in my app because there isn't any built in function to track share buttons right away. 
I already use Google Analytics for my site, do you recomend to use facebook analytics for my app or should I continue with google?